# Was Luke 17:22 added later? I don't see it mentioned in the similar passages in the other Synoptics

Tags: jesus, luke, contradiction, manuscript, synoptic-problem

*And he said to the disciples, “The days are coming when you will desire to see one of the days of the Son of Man, and you will not see it."*

Did Jesus actually say this, was this a saying added by Luke, or is it a later scribal insertion? I know a lot of early believers thought he was coming very soon, was this to combat that belief?

Comment: It is not clear what evidence you are basing your supposition upon. Are you questioning the manuscript evidence ? Otherwise this question is purely opinion based and is off-topic. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of this, an _hermeneutic_ site. Welcome to SE-BH. That wording is not present from other writers is not  justified cause to assume the wording is not a genuine report of witnessed speech.

Comment: The textual variants are in footnotes of many bibles like esv NASB NET, NHEB . Check them before asking.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I edited the question a little bit, but can roll back the changes if you don't like them)

Comment: @HoldToTheRod yeah thanks, perfect

Comment: use theword.net PC software and stepbible.org site for your study of comparison of versions and bible footnotes, variants etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Synoptic Problem**

More than a third of the Gospel of Luke is material that is not found in Matthew or Mark, so we should be cautious about assuming, a priori, that if something is found only in Luke it cannot be original to Luke's Gospel--this would rule out huge swaths of the Gospel, not just this verse.

The Synoptic Problem is all about trying understand the patterns of agreement & disagreement across Matthew, Mark, and Luke. If they always agreed or always disagreed, there would be no Synoptic Problem.

If you are interested in a technical discussion of the patterns in wording & content across the Synoptic Gospels, [this video](https://youtu.be/eKb5ZQNXHRU) on my channel may be of interest to you.

--

**Manuscript evidence**

I am unaware of any good manuscript evidence against the originality of this verse. The textual evidence decisively favors the conclusion that Luke's comments on the Parousia were not identical to those of Matthew or Mark (see also the Lukan version of the Olivet discourse in Luke 21).

--

**Timing of the Parousia**

Multiple New Testament authors explicitly acknowledge that the date of Jesus' 2nd coming was unknown. For example, Paul teaches on the matter in 1 Thessalonians, and then in 2 Thessalonians has to clarify that:

1. Paul doesn't know when the 2nd coming will be
2. It's not going to be immediate

...because they have misunderstood the comments in his prior epistle.

That some early Christians held the belief that the 2nd coming would be within their lifetimes does not mean Jesus specifically taught this (a discussion of Matt. 16:28 would probably need to be a separate question all its own).

--

**Chronology**

Some read the prophecies in the Synoptics and assume that they must reflect later Christian teachings & beliefs, not the words of Jesus Himself. Nowhere is this assumption more prevalent than in the context of the Olivet discourse. This has led many to conclude that at least Matthew & Luke were written after AD 70.

A common interpretation of the Olivet discourse is that Jesus is saying that the temple will be destroyed and He will return in glory within the lifetime of some who are present. That doesn’t make for a very impressive after-the-fact prophecy since He did not return in glory at that time. So either:

- We are misinterpreting the prophecy OR
- The Gospels recording this information were written before 70 OR
- Both

In [this video](https://youtu.be/mivjkw0Vyjc) I explore in greater depth why the post-70 argument for a fictitious "after the fact" prophecy is circular. Similar arguments could be made in response to the claim that Luke 17 must have been written after AD 70. There is no reason why this verse *couldn't* have been written after AD 70, but there is also no good reason why it couldn't have been written prior to that time.

My own study of New Testament chronology leads me to conclude that the Gospel of Luke was written before Paul traveled to Rome (arrived ~AD 60).

--

**Did Jesus Really Say This?**

Jesus was an itinerant teacher and would have taught the same sermons and told the same stories more than once--there is no reason to believe He would have preached using exactly the same words every time, nor to expect that eyewitnesses would remember & translate His teachings identically.

Since every word attributed to Jesus in the Gospels can be read aloud in under an hour, and Jesus' ministry appears to have lasted a little more than 3 years, none of the Gospels are anything close to a full transcript of all of His teachings (see also John 21:25). As such, it should not surprise us when one Gospel records a teaching not found in the others (all 4 Gospels each have content unique to themselves).

As to whether a statement in the Gospels is a) a direct quote from Jesus, b) a paraphrase of something He taught, or c) an insertion by a later writer...this is an immense subject all its own. Those who believe the inspiration of the Bible will generally accept possibilities a and/or b. Those who presuppose naturalism (an odd thing to do when studying a book about the supernatural) will generally accept possibility c.

[My own work](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGACqQS4ut5iFeKqqvQPK_dzMnjF7NBhw) on the history of the Gospels leads me to conclude that Luke is a highly reliable historian who personally knew multiple people who were in attendance during this particular sermon, and who worked carefully with eyewitness material. On this basis, one need not accept or reject any particular theological framework in order to conclude that if a highly reliable historian reported that Jesus said this, He probably did say it.

Comment: Yeah I agree. Personally I think Matthew 16:28 is in reference to the Transfiguration, it always happens like a week or so before it. I also don't think Matthew was written post AD 70, I happen to subscribe to Matthean priority (used to be Markan) just because the reasoning of scholars for it to be Mark first seems to me arrogant and naturalistic for no reason.

Anyway, thanks !

Comment: @John-Clement I used to believe in Markan Priority as well, but it left me with lots of unanswered questions, so I went back to first principals and became persuaded that Matthean Priority is a much stronger argument. I made a [video series](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGACqQS4ut5iFeKqqvQPK_dzMnjF7NBhw) about it if you're in to the topic.